Is there a client tool that allows me to send normal HTTP/2 requests, and also send TLS 1.3 Early Data requests via HTTP/2?
I've set up a server and I want to serve TLS1.3 Early Data requests via HTTP/2. The server uses OpenSSL 1.1.1 (switching to OpenSSL 3.0 very soon), and the client uses OpenSSL 3.3;
For example, for HTTP/1.1, one can simply do:
openssl s_client -connect <IP>:443 -tls1_3 -sess_out session.pem -ign_eof < request.txt 
& then
openssl s_client -connect <IP>:443 -tls1_3 -sess_in session.pem -early_data request.txt
with request.txt being

GET /example.html HTTP/1.1
Host: <examplehost.com>
Connection: close

Both times, the request is served correctly.
How do I do this via HTTP/2?
(If it matters, the server is not nginx, but even nginx solutions would help.)
What I've tried
Simply adding -alpn h2 to the s_client command didn't cut it here, because I can't send request.txt as is because of the change in format in http/2 to frames. I managed to find a code snippet online that seems to create raw frames to pipe into openssl s_client here: https://gist.github.com/stephenlb/462bfefb99fe06133e029e6bd6720e6c (there's a bug in it with a missing comma, and it needs to be run in python2)
Editing that to contain the right values, I'm able to do something like:
python2 http2-request.py | openssl s_client -alpn h2 -tls1_3 -connect <IP>:443 -sess_out session.pem
This results in a fairly odd scenario though; on checking my server-side logs, it seems that it's very inconsistent in even being able to read the data; 5/6 times it simply says there was no data to read. On occasion though, I'm able to read in the headers and process the request; but it also seems like s_client immediately closes the connection, not allowing a response to be written back.
My suspicions are strengthened by the fact that on checking Wireshark on client-side; immediately after the HTTP/2 request by the client, I see a client-to-server TLS 1.3 Close Notify message being sent. So it seems that even in the rare scenario of the server even receiving and reading the headers, it's unable to write a response back because s_client closes immediately.
Even if we were to just ignore that and focus only on Early Data: writing the output of http2-request.py to a file (http2request.txt) and passing it to -early_data as so:
openssl s_client -connect <IP>:443 -alpn h2 -tls1_3 -sess_in session.pem -early_data http2request.txt
also seems to have no effect; calls to SSL_read_early_data on my server simply result in a direct finished message for this; (for HTTP/1.1 requests it works as expected, i.e reads in the early data into my buffer and I'm able to process and serve the request.)
This all probably stems from the hack-y way of using s_client for http/2 requests, but I'm not aware of any other client that can send http/2 requests and also supports TLS 1.3 Early Data.
I've also tried:

curl: has http/2 support but not early data
nghttp2 client (i.e nghttp): same as above, as far as I can tell
h2c: same as above

Hence, I turn to y'all on StackOverflow for help. Are there any clients that can do what I'm trying to do, and what kind of setup will I need to do to get it working?
